# Tkinter listbox that scrolls with arrow keys

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to get my listbox to have the first object highlighted (which happens with `self.e1.select_set(0)`. I am now trying to scroll through the listbox highlighting the next item down when hitting the down arrow, or select the next item up by hitting the up arrow. I thought that I could do this with binding but no luck. Any ideas?

```
 def body(self, master):        
    self.e1 = tk.Listbox(master, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, height = 3, exportselection=0)
    self.e1.insert(tk.END, "1")
    self.e1.insert(tk.END, "2")

    self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.e1.select_set(0)

    self.e1.bind("<Down>", self.OnEntryDown)
    self.e1.bind("<Up>", self.OnEntryUp)

def OnEntryDown(self, event):
    self.e1.yview_scroll(1, "units")

def OnEntryUp(self, event):
    self.e1.yview_scroll(-1, "units")
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? Do you get an error? What error? Do you get no error, but you get unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name says, `yview_scroll` only changes the view, not the selection.

Like you select the first object with `select_set(0)`, you can also use `select_set` to select the other objects. Keep a reference to which object is selected and use that to select the next or previous object upon button press. Just make sure that the selection does not go below 0 or over the size of the listbox.

Code example:

```
def body(self, master):        
    self.e1 = tk.Listbox(master, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, height = 3, exportselection=0)
    self.e1.insert(tk.END, "1")
    self.e1.insert(tk.END, "2")

    self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.selection = 0
    self.e1.select_set(self.selection)

    self.e1.bind("<Down>", self.OnEntryDown)
    self.e1.bind("<Up>", self.OnEntryUp)

def OnEntryDown(self, event):
    if self.selection < self.e1.size()-1:
        self.e1.select_clear(self.selection)
        self.selection += 1
        self.e1.select_set(self.selection)

def OnEntryUp(self, event):
    if self.selection > 0:
        self.e1.select_clear(self.selection)
        self.selection -= 1
        self.e1.select_set(self.selection)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a slight improvement on fhdrsdg's answer it is not required to separately keep track of the selected id. The first value of widget.curselection() can be used since the listbox mode is set to single selection.

```
def body(self, master):        
    self.e1 = tk.Listbox(master, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, height = 3, exportselection=0)
    self.e1.insert(tk.END, "1")
    self.e1.insert(tk.END, "2")

    self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.e1.select_set(0)

    self.e1.bind("<Down>", self.OnEntryUpDown)
    self.e1.bind("<Up>", self.OnEntryUpDown)

def OnEntryUpDown(self, event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()[0]
    
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        selection += -1

    if event.keysym == 'Down':
        selection += 1

    if 0 <= selection < event.widget.size():
        event.widget.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
        event.widget.select_set(selection)
```